# Add wifi password to keychain using Objective C/Swift on OSX?

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, wifi, keychain

Is it possible to edit/add/remove wifi entries in keychain using Objective C or Swift on OSX?

I have this command working for terminal to add a wifi entry but was wondering if there was another way.  One of the big down sides to this method is it prompts for a system username and password every time.

```
security add-generic-password -a "RESTO  Slimut Lidah" -l "WifiMap - RESTO  Slimut Lidah" -D "AirPort network password" -s "AirPort" -w "8787318a" -T /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport -T /usr/libexec/airportd -T group://Airport -U /Library/Keychains/System.keychain
```

Comment: @Willeke I tried the terminal command but it prompts me for a system username and password for each entry.

Comment: Try searching Apple's developer documentation for 'keychain'. You'll find 'Keychain Services Reference'.

Comment: @Willeke, thanks.  I've looked through the docs but I haven't been able to find anything that mentions adding wifi passwords...

Comment: Your security command does add-generic-password.

Comment: @Willeke but it prompts me for a password for each entry and I want to add a few hundred.

Comment: I found [SecKeychainAddGenericPassword](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/#//apple_ref/c/func/SecKeychainAddGenericPassword) in the docs, you could try to use it. I also found the sources of [security](http://opensource.apple.com/release/os-x-10112/).

Comment: https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2011/05/17/setting-preferred-wireless-networks-from-the-command-line/